# Merge Segment Ranges Based on Grouped Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of segments with a beginning point, an ending point, and a value like so:

```
Bmp | Emp | SomeVal
0     1     1
1     2     1
2     3     2
3     4     2
4     5     1
```

I would like to merge (summarize) these records so they look like so:

```
Bmp | Emp | SomeVal
0     2     1
2     4     2
4     5     1
```

I've simplified my data set for the purpose of this question. The end result is I need unique rows grouped by the SomeVal column (in my real data set, there are about 20 columns) with the segments stitched together from Bmp to Emp, but not overlapping.

I've tried the following:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Bmp int, Emp int, SomeVal int)

INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT 0, 1, 1 UNION
SELECT 1, 2, 1 UNION
SELECT 2, 3, 2 UNION
SELECT 3, 4, 2 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, 1

SELECT MIN(Bmp) AS Bmp, Max(Emp) AS Emp, SomeVal FROM @tbl
GROUP BY SomeVal
```

Unfortunately, it comes out like so which is wrong:

```
Bmp | Emp | SomeVal
0     5     1
2     4     2
```

My query above only works if the values of SomeVal do not repeat. How can I fix my sql?

Minimum required version is SQL 2008.

Comment: if you want to group by SomeVal, why you want that to be repeated in result set unless group by clause have more that one field?

Comment: While the answer given below technically works, the problem of "Islands and Gaps" is a somewhat common issue that you might be interested in doing research on. For example, your issue could very easily be solved with a simple query grouping by the difference of row numbers (e.g. `SELECT Bmp = MIN(Bmp), Emp = MAX(Emp), SomeVal FROM (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Bmp) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeVal ORDER BY Bmp) FROM @tbl) T GROUP BY SomeVal, RN ORDER BY MIN(Bmp);`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may using ROW_NUMBER() function to correlate begin group row with end group row.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Bmp int, Emp int, SomeVal int)

INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT 0, 1, 1 UNION
SELECT 1, 2, 1 UNION
SELECT 2, 3, 2 UNION
SELECT 3, 4, 2 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, 1

;WITH
[Begins] AS
(
    SELECT Bmp, SomeVal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Bmp) AS OrderNumber
    FROM @tbl AS [Begin]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @tbl AS [Prev] 
        WHERE [Prev].Emp = [Begin].Bmp AND [Prev].SomeVal = [Begin].SomeVal)
),
[Ends] AS
(
    SELECT Emp, SomeVal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Emp) AS OrderNumber
    FROM @tbl AS [End]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @tbl AS [Next]
        WHERE [Next].Bmp = [End].Emp AND [Next].SomeVal = [End].SomeVal)
)
SELECT [Begins].Bmp, [Ends].Emp, [Begins].SomeVal
FROM [Begins]
INNER JOIN [Ends]
    ON [Begins].OrderNumber = [Ends].OrderNumber;
```

Comment: In general, I would suggest not using table aliases like 'begin' and 'end' (or any other reserved word), even with the square brackets.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another option...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    Bmp INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
    Emp INT NOT NULL, 
    SomeVal INT NOT NULL
    );
INSERT #TestData (Bmp, Emp, SomeVal) 
SELECT 0, 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 5, 1;

--==============================================

WITH 
    cte_GroupStart AS (
        SELECT 
            td.Bmp, 
            td.Emp, 
            td.SomeVal,
            GroupStart = CASE WHEN td.SomeVal = LAG(td.SomeVal, 1) OVER (ORDER BY td.Bmp) THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY td.Bmp) END 
        FROM
            #TestData td
        ),
    cte_FillGroup AS (
        SELECT 
            gs.Bmp, 
            gs.Emp, 
            gs.SomeVal, 
            AggGroup = MAX(gs.GroupStart) OVER (ORDER BY gs.Bmp)    --  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING is implied and should work as expected 2008
        FROM
            cte_GroupStart gs
        )
SELECT 
    Bmp = MIN(fg.Bmp),
    Emp = MAX(fg.Emp),
    fg.SomeVal
FROM
    cte_FillGroup fg
GROUP BY
    fg.AggGroup,
    fg.SomeVal
ORDER BY 
    fg.AggGroup;
```

Comment: LAG isn't supported on SQL 2008